# Redirect to a webpage when URL points to directory (using .htaccess)

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have the following problem. I want to redirect all of requests that point to a specific directory  (.htaccess is placed in it). Shortly speaking I want to use the following rules:

1.

```
www.domain.com/directoryThatContainsHtaccess
=>
www.domain.com/directoryThatContainsHtaccess/specificPage.htm
```

2.

```
www.domain.com/directoryThatContainsHtaccess/
=>
www.domain.com/directoryThatContainsHtaccess/specificPage.htm
```

3.

```
www.domain.com/directoryThatContainsHtaccess/somePage.htm
=>
no redirection
```

I have tried the following code but without any luck (I have end up with redirection loop):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/directoryThatContainsHtaccess/specificPage.htm [R=301,L]
```

I think `^$` is incorrect.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `^$` is correct pattern for no URL (i.e. directory hit). #2 should work ... but #1 should not (as it is not explicitly declared as directory (no trailing slash`/`)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a condition for file-name with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`, give the following a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* specificPage.htm [R=301,L]
```